# How to pass an array into an SQL statement and submit it to a database?

Tags: sql

How to pass an array into an SQL statement and submit it to a database ?

Comment: I'm completely unclear on what you are trying to do. Do you want to insert multiple rows?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Could you give a specific scenario, or some more details?

Comment: Specifically, what exactly do you mean by "submit it". Does that mean split the array values into multiple rows and save them? Does that mean saving the entire array into a single column?

Comment: basically i have input fields that are added with jQuery on the pressing of a button it appends the name of the input to input[] i want to store all of that data which is stored in an array called children into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL this is quite easy:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_column, array_column)
VALUES
(42, ARRAY[4,2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server you can pass XML parameters into a stored procedure and then do a select on the nodes within the SP itself.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx

Comment: More options: Just do lots of inserts, use tab or newline separated values, etc. Basically there are loads of ways, it depends where you want to put it.